# CentOS 7: Nginx systemctl hangs on start, why?

Tags: centos, nginx, mod-pagespeed, page-speed, systemctl

I compiled `nginx with pagespeed` and made the `nginx.service` file in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service` but when i try to do `systemctl start nginx` it just hangs, nginx does start but systemctl hangs.
 I have to use `ctrl+c` to get out.

Comment: Admin installed unit should go in `/etc/systemd`, not `/usr/lib/systemd` (but that wouldn't cause your issue). You should add the contents of your unit file.

Comment: I did fix it, there was some problem in the file.
Now i just copied the file that comes with the pre built package from yum and it worked.